# Can I tile a background image a certain number of times?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I know how to make a tiled background in HTML using the repeat element, but I was wondering if I could get the image to repeat a certain number of times? Is there any way I can control that...?

Comment: This is also another hack you could use. ^^

Answer (score -2):

Sadly, there is not CSS option for this, The best hack you could get is to make more divs with this background and have them placed where you need them.
I have also heard that there is a way to do it with jquery, but that is beyond my knowledge, so you could look there.